# Why do basketball players wear hoodies/long-sleeves on the sidelines?

Tags: basketball

Regardless of whether or not the player has already been on the court or started on the bench, many NBA basketball players will wear a long-sleeve shirt or a hoodie while sitting on the bench.

Including but not limited to players like James Harden, LeBron James, and Kyrie Irving - usually wear some sort of long-sleeve shirt while on the bench.

At first glance, shouldn't returning players' top priority on the bench to 'cool-down', regain energy to go back in (especially the star players), and dry whatever sweat is on their body? I don't understand the purpose of wearing a hoodie on the sidelines after playing x amount of mins. I feel like wearing a hoodie while sweating profusely will only heat the body up more.

Comment: In general, you don't want to cool down too much, because you become inflexible. I can't quote a source, but NBA venues are heavily air-conditioned. So players are wearing hoodies to prevent cooling down but rather remain at a modest temperature.

Comment: Good point, but (to play devil's advocate) couldn't the same be said about boxing/UFC? Athletes will commonly wear a cool towel around the back of the neck and drink cool drinks in between rounds- I'm sure it's A/C'd there heavily as well? I don't recall athletes wearing hoodies while resting

Comment: How long are the breaks in between boxing rounds? 2 minutes? In the NBA, you are easily out for 10 minutes.